# IEnumerable doesn't Add items

Tags: c#, .net, list, loops, ienumerable

Why an `IEnumerable` is not adding items?

This code add items to "values" list:

```
List<String> values = new List<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < ddlTransportadora.Items.Count; i++)
{
    values.Add(ddlTransportadora.Items[i].Value);
}
```

But this code makes the loop, and after values doesn't have items:

```
IEnumerable<String> values = new List<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < ddlTransportadora.Items.Count; i++)
{
    values.Add(ddlTransportadora.Items[i].Value);
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: I'm surprised that the second example compiles (assuming it even does compile). `IEnumerable` does not have an `Add`.

Comment: There is no method `Add` in the `IEnumerable<T>` interface.

Comment: Plus, what is wrong with the first example? The reason your work with `IEnumerable` is generally that you want to iterate or use LINQ but don't care if it is a `List` or `Array` that is the underlying source. Not because you want to add things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `Add` method defined in `IList<T>` interface, and `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't inherit from `IList<T>`.You can use this instead:

```
IList<String> values = new List<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < ddlTransportadora.Items.Count; i++)
{
    values.Add(ddlTransportadora.Items[i].Value);
}
```

Comment: And may i add that coming from the word `Enumerable` isn't it weird that you'd be able to add?

Answer (score 0):

All of these will give you an `IEnumerable<string>`:

You can use an explicit constructor to build and populate your collection:

- `new List<String>( ddlTransportadora.Items.Select( x => x.Value ) )`

You can use LINQ to create an enumerable collection on the fly:

- `ddlTransportadora.Items.Select( x => x.Value ).ToList()`
- `ddlTransportadora.Items.Select( x => x.Value ).ToArray()`

You can even skip creating an actual collection and simply use LINQ deferred execution to provide an enumerable view of your data:

- `ddlTransportadora.Items.Select( x => x.Value )`

Why try to make things any more complicated than they need to be?